# Привязка SDL

Tags: sdl, d

Перебрался на D и задумал один проект. Но никак не могу настроить привязку и документацию для этого языка. Можете что-либо посоветовать?

Comment: подробности?

Comment: подробности чего ?
не могу найти привязку sdl к языку D.
Что можете посоветовать ?

Comment: Посоветовать выбросить D?

Comment: @VladimirGordeev лол

Comment: Пробуйте https://github.com/DerelictOrg/DerelictSDL2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда сам ковырялся с Ди, то использовал [Derelict](http://www.dsource.org/projects/derelict/).
Какова поддержка на данный момент -- ХЗ.

Answer (score 0):

DerelictSDL

Пример использования - посмотрите реализацию в DlangUI

[SDL backend для DlangUI](https://github.com/buggins/dlangui/blob/master/src/dlangui/platforms/sdl/sdlapp.d)